# Как правильно настроить выпадающий список?

Tags: html, css

Написал небольшое меню с выпадающим списком для наглядности, интересует 3 вопроса:

1. Как сделать, чтобы выпадающий список появлялся НАД а не ПОД родителем?
2. Как сделать, чтобы выпадающий список начинался от правого края родителя и продолжался в левую сторону?
3. Как сделать, чтобы при отсутствие места с права, выпадающий список занимал свободное место с лева?

Картинка для вопроса 3:
[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

.list.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list.parent>.item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.list.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  background: greenyellow;
}

.list.dropdown>.item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list parent">
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li class="item item-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Item</a>
    <ul class="list dropdown">
      <li class="item"><a href="#">Item child 1</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">Item child 2</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">Item child 3</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">Item child 4</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">Item child 5</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">Item child 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Элементу `ul.list.parent` задать `position: relative` а `ul.list.dropdown`- `position: absolute` и `bottom: 100%;`
2. Элементу `ul.list.dropdown` задать `right: 0;`, при этом у элемента `ul.parent .item` НЕ должно быть задано свойство `position`, иначе `ul.dropdown` будет позиционироваться относительно этого элемента, а не относительно всего меню
3. Тут немного по сложнее, ведь выпадающее меню спозиционированно абсолютно...
   Можно задать width: 100%, тогда выпадающее меню будет такой же ширины, как и меню первого уровня.
   Можно задать фиксированную ширину, но если у вас адаптив, то этот вариант тоже не подойдет.